# How to get title of a link using php Domdocument

Tags: php, regex, dom, curl, domdocument

I have created a script to get href value from a link.But i want to get the title of the link too in an two dimensional array.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($searched);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) {
    $links[] = $lnk->getAttribute('href');
}

 <a href="sdfsdgdgs">$Title</a>
```

Title means the content between the a tag
Please help me ..

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there!

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($searched);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) 
{
    $links[] = array(
        'href' => $lnk->getAttribute('href'),
        'title' => $lnk->getAttribute('title')
    );
}
```

Now each element in `$links` will look something like this:

```
Array (
    [href] => http://google.com
    [title] => Google
)
```

Comment: I mean <a href="gsdgg">$title</a>

Comment: I want to get the above title(
$title)

Comment: Yes I got it                                                                  echo $dom->textContent;
echo $dom->nodeValue;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lnk->item(0)->nodeValue;
```